# Scala nested map merge

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I would like to merge nested maps, but I can't figure out how to merge the inner maps.

```
var a = Map[String,Map[String,String]]()
a = a + ("key1" -> Map("subkey1" -> "a"))
a = a + ("key1" -> Map("subkey2" -> "b"))
a = a + ("key2" -> Map("subkey1" -> "c"))
```

I would like to merge all of these such that I get the following result:

```
Map("key1" -> Map("subkey1" -> "a", "subkey2" -> "b"), "key2" -> Map("subkey1" -> "c"))
```

Is there any standard method for this?

Comment: What if there is a collision between keys in the sub-map? Like two `subkey1` under the `key1` map.

Comment: @m-z Ideally that collision could be handled by a 2-arity function. In my case the signature would be more like Map[String,Map[String,Seq[String]]] and then cons (add?) the values together.

Answer (score 1):

If it's fine to use Scalaz - [semigroups](http://www.inoio.de/blog/2014/07/19/type-class-101-semigroup/) may help:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
val map1 = Map("key1" -> Map("subkey1" -> "a"))
val map2 = Map("key1" -> Map("subkey2" -> "b"))
val map3 = Map("key2" -> Map("subkey1" -> "c"))

scala> map1 |+| map2 |+| map3
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = 
   Map(key2 -> Map(subkey1 -> c), key1 -> Map(subkey2 -> b, subkey1 -> a))
```

The only restriction - your value should have [Semigroup](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.Semigroup) defined in order to handle collisions:

```
trait A
object A1 extends A
object A2 extends A 

implicit val ASemigroup = new Semigroup[A] {
  def append(a: A, b: => A) : A = a //"choose first" strategy
}

val map1 = Map("key1" -> Map("subkey1" -> (A1: A)))
val map2 = Map("key1" -> Map("subkey1" -> (A2: A)))

scala> map1 |+| map2
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,A]] = 
   Map(key1 -> Map(subkey1 -> A1$@2cb79bd1))
```

Btw, strings already have Semigroup defined on them, so collision will lead to string's concatenation there.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything that works well for this that's built in, but `getOrElse` is your friend here.  The core of the logic, if you are sure there are no submap collections, looks like

```
val x = a.getOrElse(key, mutable.Map.empty[String,String])
a = a + (key -> (x ++ subMap))
```

If you may have a collision, you need to do something other than `++`--possibly use the same trick again to get the subkey and update the value if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there isn't direct method provided for this. You can provide a helper method.

```
def mergeUpdate[K1, K2, V](base: Map[K1, Map[K2, V]], tuple: (K1, Map[K2, V])) = {
  base + (tuple._1 -> (base.getOrElse(tuple._1, Map.empty) ++ tuple._2))
}
```

then rewrite your code:

```
var a = Map[String,Map[String,String]]()
a = mergeUpdate(a, ("key1" -> Map("subkey1" -> "a")))
a = mergeUpdate(a, ("key1" -> Map("subkey2" -> "b")))
a = mergeUpdate(a, ("key2" -> Map("subkey1" -> "c")))

// =>
a: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Map[String,String]] = Map(key1 -> Map(subkey1 -> a, subkey2 -> b), key2 -> Map(subkey1 -> c))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can pull other dependencies, you can try this

```
scala> import com.daodecode.scalax.collection.extensions._
import com.daodecode.scalax.collection.extensions._

scala> val m1 = "key1" -> Map("subkey1" -> "a")
m1: (String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]) = (key1,Map(subkey1 -> a))

scala> val m2 = "key1" -> Map("subkey2" -> "b")
m2: (String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]) = (key1,Map(subkey2 -> b))

scala> val m3 = "key2" -> Map("subkey1" -> "c")
m3: (String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]) = (key2,Map(subkey1 -> c))

scala> Seq(m1, m2, m3).toCompleteMap.
  mapValues(_.foldLeft(Map.empty[String,String]){ 
    case (acc, m) => acc.mergedWith(m)(_ + _)})
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = Map(key2 -> Map(subkey1 -> c), key1 -> Map(subkey1 -> a, subkey2 -> b))
```

[toCompleteMap](https://github.com/jozic/scalax-collection#tocompletemap) and [mergedWith](https://github.com/jozic/scalax-collection#mergedwith) are extensions methods from https://github.com/jozic/scalax-collection. It's published to maven central

`(_ + _)` here is your own collision resolution function